# Get file with Javascript after login

Tags: javascript, php

I want to run a javascript which gets a .php file from another Server, which is secured with a login. I have the full login data and right to use the code.

So my question is, how can javascript automatically login to this website and then run the code? Do I need an extra PHP-File?

Downloading the file from the other server isn´t an option for me.

My example code:

```
$.get('http://domain.com/file.php',  function(data) {
    if(CODE) {
        CODE
    } else {
        CODE
    }
```

Comment: Yes. You need to curl with credentials unless the other site has set up CORS for you to use

Comment: do not do this via client side scripting language. PHP is your best bet. CURL is an option.

Comment: How would a curl work in my example?

Comment: check http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php